# 'unsubscribed' and 'held' clean up Salesforce Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

Can I know how we are charged for Salesforce Marketing Cloud in terms of contact? Is it based on number of subscribers in 'All Subscribers' list or is it subscribers for each publication list we have? We want to clean up 'unsubscribed' and 'held'. Should we clean this for each publication or only for the master list? Any reference to salesforce doc will be good to see.

Comment: This may be a question better answered by your Salesforce account representative.

Comment: You are billed for contacts, not for subscribers. You can find a good explanation here, on how they are counted: [How are Contacts in Marketing Cloud counted?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/292459/how-are-contacts-in-marketing-cloud-counted)

Comment: Thanks Lukas. How do you guys deal with held? Do you remove them?