# Billable Contacts Count in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

The only sendable records in our SFMC org are contacts, leads and users synchronized from our sales/service cloud account with marketing cloud connect.
I have filtered our synchronized objects to only allow some records into SFMC based on criteria - but our billable counts still show the total number of contacts/leads in our sales/service account and not only what is filtered to go into SFMC.

Is there something else I need to do to make sure our billable contacts only include what we want in marketing cloud, and not what is in sales/service cloud?

Answer (score 1):

Applying filters to synchronized objects does not remove contacts that were already synchronized from MC, so you need to find those that are not longer synchronized and perform a deletion yourself.

Refer to this article for guidance and best practices about deletions:

[Permanently remove Contacts or Subscribers and associated data from Contact Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000313920&type=1)

Comment: Wolsztyniak how would I find the ones that were already synchronized? I am still new to marketing cloud and the link you sent doesn't seem to be helping. I tried the steps and it does not find anything.

Comment: Cairo, you need to write an SQL query that compares the list of all billable contacts with the synchronized data extension with contacts from Salesforce and outputs only those that exist in All Contacts, but are not in your synchronized data extensions. I describe how to get this list in a data extension here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/292459/how-are-contacts-in-marketing-cloud-counted/292482#292482 (you just need contact builder for this)

Comment: thank you for your response. We do not use populations or anything else though. We only use salesforce synchronized contacts. And the SQL query is pulling nothing. I am also worried about accidentally deleting contacts that we still need in SFMC as well. Sorry if I am asking repetitive questions - again I am very new to SFMC

Comment: @MelissaCairo, no worries, this is a complex issue that has a solution that requires some experience. In the linked article I explain how to create a list that mimics the All Contacts list, if you have done that step, does the number of found contacts show a similar number to that from All Contacts?

Comment: The all contacts list I have now is only showing contacts that we have going through an active journey (which is running based off salesforce data) - so only about 700. And then my synchronized objects in salesforce that are sendable add up to about 57,000 contacts - but according to the billing contacts in the report, we have 90,000. Not sure where the extra 30,000 or so contacts are coming from