# Why "User" Synchronized data extension is sendable ? as it is consuming unnecessary Marking cloud contacts licenses can we make non-sendable?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

We observed Leads and Contacts Synchronized Data extensions are sendable ..can we change them from sendable to non-sendable to save marketing cloud contacts licenses ?

Also why User Synchronized DE is also sendable ? can we make that is non-sendable or simply delete/remove from Data sources > Synchronized DE ? as it is consuming Marketing cloud valuable contacts licenses

Also can we delete all the contacts from "User" Sync DE permanently using Contact deletion without any impact on the system ?

other question is in case of multi-org connector in our project below is the situation / integration of different orgs

1. Production CRM connected to Prod BU of SFMC
2. Staging CRM (full copy sandbox) connected to Staging BU of SFMC
3. Dev CRM connected to Dev BU of SFMC
   and if we refresh Staging CRM (which is our Full Sandbox) with Production CRM then in that case all ContactIDs , LeadIDs will get copy from Production CRM to Staging CRM ? so in that case we can not consider all the records synced from Staging CRM to Marketing Cloud Staging BU?

Comment: Hope this answer all your queries ... https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/292459/how-are-contacts-in-marketing-cloud-counted

Answer (score 4):

***Why "User" Synchronized data extension is sendable?***

That's because it has email addresses and the User is considered as one of the sendable objects, along with Contact and Lead.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cab_contact_definition_and_count_determination.htm&type=5

***As it is consuming unnecessary Marking cloud contacts licenses can we make it non-sendable?***

Unfortunately not, you cannot edit any of the settings of the Synchronized Data Extensions. You need to sync the Contact, Lead, and User objects to be able to then synch further objects from Salesforce. Some accounts that don't use Leads or Contacts at all also struggle with this, but there is no way to get around it.

The only thing that comes to my mind to limit the number of Users (if you don't intend of using them for anything), is to use some sort of filtering so that you only synch a subset of the Users or none at all - for example, filter by a flag that is by default set to `false` for all your Users.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_implement_synchronized_data_sources_best_practices.htm&type=5

***Also can we delete all the contacts from "User" Sync DE permanently using Contact deletion without any impact on the system ?***

You cannot delete anything from a Synchronized DE, it's not possible technically. You can limit the number of Users synched as outlined in the previous point and then you can delete the unneeded contacts (representing Users) from Marketing Cloud contacts using Contact Delete. No impact on the system if you haven't been using them for anything.

**To address your last question, take a look at the graph and explanation below:**

> This figure shows how some contact records can overlap in business
> units, but other contacts can remain available only to a particular
> business unit.

> Contacts count only one time. Marketing Cloud
> automatically de-duplicates multiple instances of a contact in a
> population based on the Contact Key value.

[image]

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cab_contact_definition_and_count_determination.htm&type=5

I would assume that contacts who are identified by the same Contact Key (Salesforce Id) would count only once towards the contact count, but I would create an SF Support case to double-check.