# Is there any downsides to using the `User_Salesforce` synchronizer in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

From my understanding in order to sync data related to a contact in using Marketing Cloud Connect, the `User_Salesforce` synchronizer must be added however what if `Contact_Salesforce` is also used?

I would like to conditionally use related data using SQL to create data extensions. Based on [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/292459/how-are-contacts-in-marketing-cloud-counted) it appears that `Contact_Salesforce` and `User_Salesforce` individually count as billable contacts.

**Questions:**

1. I don't entirely understand what kind of records are within `User_Salesforce`. Is it contacts or the users used to login to salesforce, etc?
2. Would adding `User_Salesforce` result in duplicate billable contact count for the same contact? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users in Salesforce are people in your organisation who are logging in and working in Salesforce Sales/Service Cloud. This object holds a number of fields, which are listed [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm). They are indeed billable, once they are synchronised to SFMC, but normally the number of Users compared to your Contacts and Leads is negligible.

This also means that they will not be duplicates of your Contacts and Leads, as these are normally not part of your organisation.

Comment: Oh very interesting! As you mentioned the number of users logging into Sales Cloud is quite low. I wonder why synchronizers for data related to `Contact_Salesforce` needs to have `User_Salesforce` enabled when they seemingly have no relation to `Contact_Salesforce`.

Comment: @PatrickNomad there is a lookup field on Contact record, linking the Contact with its owner, which is a user, hence (I assume) the prerequisite, as you would need to know the owner not just by ID. It is also listed in the [doc here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_cab_synch_object_relationship_priority.htm&type=5).

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the above - a "not so normal" but plausible scenario where I almost ran into synchronizing millions of users by mistake is:

"Salesforce Identity / Experience Cloud / Community Cloud", where the user object is used to create profiles for the respective login, on a cheaper-than-usual license model: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5 - this can rack up. Usually you'd run into anything from a handful to couple thousand, which is rather negligible indeed.

This can be avoided as with the other two billable objects, make it a practice to by default always create a Boolean "SynchToSFMC" Field on User that you set to false on all records *before* you hit the "synch" button. That way you synch empty tables, which will get rid of all synch constraints without risking blindly creating billable records. Once you know what is going on, set the field to true where relevant.